# Does an iOS app continue to run in the background after an App Store update?

Tags: iphone, ios

For example: would a VOIP app, which has an open socket which is notified of incoming traffic before the App Store update, have a chance to re-establish that socket after an App Store update? Or does the App have to wait for the user to open the App first? I can't find any answer to this in any Apple documentation.

Comment: Try it yourself using an AdHoc build.

Comment: @rmaddy Or even Dev installs with new version numbers. I bet those are the exact same as App Store updates.

Comment: Take a look at the UIBackgroundModes section in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) - VoIP apps may get special treatment.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the app is shut down (terminated) before updating, and I don't believe that the system automatically restarts them after updating (geofencing and related tasks should still work, though).

Think about it: when you get an update for Bob's Awesome Application on your desktop, you have to shutdown the app before installing the update.

After the update is installed, Bob's Awesome Application doesn't restart itself - that would just be weird - and quite annoying.